# adding libraries to VS Code for g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

trying to translate this documentation https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment for getting visual studio ready to compile vulkan code to work with VS Code.

so far VS Code generates this g++ commandline (without the line breaks):

```
C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\MSYS2\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g 
C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\code\vulkantest.cpp -o 
C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\code\vulkantest.exe
-I C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\glfw-3.3.7.bin.WIN64\include
-I C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\glm-0.9.9.8\ 
-I C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\vulkan_sdk-1.3.204.1\Include\ 
-L C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\vulkan_sdk-1.3.204.1\Lib 
-L C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\glfw-3.3.7.bin.WIN64\lib-vc2022
```

now in the screenshots from the link above they "add" glfw3.lib and vulkan1.lib, adding just glfw3.lib like this does not work:

`C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\MSYS2\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\code\vulkantest.cpp -o C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\code\vulkantest.exe -I C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\glfw-3.3.7.bin.WIN64\include -I C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\glm-0.9.9.8\ -I C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\vulkan_sdk-1.3.204.1\Include\ -L C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\vulkan_sdk-1.3.204.1\Lib -L C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\glfw-3.3.7.bin.WIN64\lib-vc2022 -lglfw3.lib C:/Users/MYUSER/development/vulkan/MSYS2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3.lib: No such file or directory collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

this file:

```
"C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\glfw-3.3.7.bin.WIN64\lib-vc2022\glfw3.dll"
```

does exist.

how do you add that library in windows/VS Code?

Comment: `.lib` is for MSVC, MinGW uses `.a`. `-l???` will search for `lib???.a`/`lib???.dll.a`, you don't need to spell the extension in the flag. Find a tutorial that deals with MinGW, it'll be easier.

Comment: -lvulkan-1 -lglfw3 errors with: ....lib-vc2022/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/window.obj):(.text$mn+0x18): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'. google says that maybe gdi32 is missing which the "big" visual studio adds automatically. but running it like this: -LC:\Windows\SysWOW64\ -lgdi32 -lvulkan-1 -lglfw3 gives the same errors

Comment: Again, MinGW needs .a files. Don't try to use .lib with it.

Comment: isnt .a the linux version for .lib somehow? i want to run vulkan on windows and as the link in the question shows this is possible with visual studio so it should be possible with mingw/vs code?

Comment: MSVC uses .lib and GCC normally uses .a, regardless if it's on Windows (i.e. MinGW) or not. The bottom line is that libs compiled with MSVC don't work with MinGW, and vice versa. I think there's some limited compatibility for C libs, but you shouldn't rely on it if possible.